# running a node exec with sudo

Tags: node.js, sudo, mount

I'm looking to create a network mounting script in Node that allows the user to mount nfs shares on the server. My code is as follows:

```
// Create our mount string command.
var str = 'mount -o nolock -t nfs '+ escapePath(p) +' '+ escapePath(mountPoint);

exec(str, function(err, stdout, stderr){
  if (err) return fn(err);
  return fn(null, mountPoint);
});
```

But, of course, mounting a network share requires `sudo`. If I run my node app using sudo, this works fine... but I suspect that this isn't the best approach. Is there a way that I can run the mount command without invoking sudo? ... or at least, without running my app using sudo? What's the best approach here?

Comment: If you use [`spawn()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) rather than `exec()`, you can specify a `uid` or `gid` for the command. Its `args` argument would also probably help with building the command, reducing possible issues from concatenating.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea that the `uid` or `gid` options existed with using `spawn()`. Time to read the docs in a bit more detail...